# How to use jars from a Java Project in an Android project transitively over the included Android library?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, project

The question is a bit messed up but I am trying to explain what I mean.

(1) is a Java Project used as a library with methods for accessing files and stuff.
(2) an android library for the same reason. Simple Methods for accessing files and stuff just for Android.

Right now (1) and (2) are linked in the build path for my Android project (A).
Works fine. I can access any method from these library projects or from the jars they include.
Now I have a second Android project (B).
So I want to make activities etc from (A) available for (B) by putting it in (2).

Buuuuuuuuuut:
Some of this copied code needs methods from (1) which are not available in (2) right now because (1) and (2) doesn't know about each other.

Idea:
Linking (1) only to (2) [(1) is removed from (A)] and (2) will be added as a library in (A) and (B) to have a clean hierarchical structure.

Result: it doesn't work because everything in (1) is no longer available in (A) and (B) and (2) doesn't pass through the included jars and methods from (1).

Linking (1) to (2) and to (A) and (B) at the same time boosts up the size of the resulting jar because everything is safed double.

Question:
Is there a way to link (1) to (2) and (2) to (A) and (B) but still have benefit of all underlying jar and methods in (1)?
In my theory it is logical to do it that way but Eclipse doesn't follow up this thought.
Maybe I missed out a setting or so.
In (2) I set up (1) to be exported in the hope it would solve anything.

**Problem solved:**

I already did it right but somehow Eclipse didn't react to it.
By exporting the java project (1) as a jar and including this one to (2) Eclipse finally understood to make use of the methods in (1).
Apparently removing the jar and switching back to include the java project (1) this combination still works. Reason unknown.
After several closing and starting Eclipse the result stays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can link (1) and (2) by:

1. Export (1) into a JAR file.
2. Put that JAR in the libs/ folder of (2).
3. Go into (2)'s project properties into the "Java Build Path" window.
4. Go to the "Order and Export" tab.
5. Check the box next to "Android Private Libraries"

What you just did is insert a "private" library into project (2), and indicated to project (2) to make its private libraries visible to outside sources.

Comment: This is truly witchcraft. Exported (1) as jar as the only difference to my previous attempts -> works. Removed the jar used the project (1) again instead of the jar (which is exactly the same I already tried) still works. I don't understand why it works but I don't question it. Problem solved.

Comment: Glad that helped. It's customary to accept an answer (the V sign next to the answer) if it solved your problem. It also helps others who'll encounter this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to go to the properties of your Android library project, go to Java Build Path, switch to the tab Order and Export and select the java library so that it is exposed to the Android project that uses the Android library.

Comment: Tried this already. Didn't work. The last line in my question is your explanation. Mine is just a bit too short.